# How to make a custom class be able to be received by range()?

Tags: python

range() in Python seems to accept integer as parameter only. How to make range() accept a custom class as parameter?

I've defined a class such as:

```
class MyInteger:
    def __init__(self, a:int):
        self._a = a
    def __int__(self):
        return self._a
```

And I tried:

```
n = MyInteger(5)
for i in range(n):
    print(i)
```

It always causes 'object cannot be interpreted as an integer' whether or not I defined `__int__.` Is there any way to solve this problem?

`range(n)` cannot be changed to `range(int(n))` or `range(n.get_int())`.

Comment: BTW, range(n) cannot be changed to range(int(n)) or range(n.get_int()) .

Comment: Could you inherit `int`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Implement [`__index__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__index__) to allow your class instances to be interpreted as an int

```
class MyInteger:

    def __init__(self, a:int):
        self._a = a

    def __index__(self):
        return self._a
```

```
n = MyInteger(5)
for i in range(n):
    print(i)
```